# Resize column width of a particular column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-automation

I need to resize excel particular column in a particular sheet.But not able to do so

```
Sub resizeColumn(sourceWb As String, Sheet As String, column As String)
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim sheetName As Worksheet
Dim columnname As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(sourceWb)
Set sheetName = wkbSource.Sheets(Sheet).Activate
Worksheets("Column width").Range("A5").ColumnWidth = 16
wkbSource.Close SaveChanges:=True
wkbSource.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to include how exactly you are calling this routine, since it includes arguments.

Comment: Do you actually have a worksheet called `Column Width` ?

Comment: yes ...sample one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are mixing the names and objects.
I assume from your code that you would like to call this with this manner:

```
Sub CallResizeColumn()
    Call ResizeColumn("PathToYourWorkbook.xlsm", "SheetToResize", "A5")        
End Sub
```

I have changed a bit your notation by adding a p at the beginning of your parameters (I think it is not a good practice to call them very similar to the keywords).
Please keep in mind that you need to use the full reference to your range ("workbook.worksheet.range").
(Note: when you turn off the SreenUpdating, be sure that you turning it back.)

```
Private Sub ResizeColumn(pSourceWb As String, pSheet As String, pColumn As String)
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim shSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rngColumn As Range
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(pSourceWb)
    Set shSheet = wkbSource.Sheets(pSheet)
    Set rngColumn = shSheet.Range(pColumn)
    rngColumn.ColumnWidth = 16
    'wkbSource.Close SaveChanges:=True
    wkbSource.Close
End Sub
```